# Ways to escape php-fpm's chroot and other security gotchas?

Tags: php, security, chroot

I'm looking into using php-fpm's chroot for a multiuser setup and I'm trying to collect info on the security side of things - escaping the chroot, leaking things etc. and how to prevent/contain them.

The only thing I've found so far is this: https://www.vennedey.net/blog/3-NSCD-socket-in-a-PHP-FPM-chroot-leaks-user-database

Are there other things I should consider?